# Exact role of Bluez in creating a virtual beacon

Tags: ibeacon, bluez, beacon

I use this code to transmit ibeacon profile over BLE.

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1e 02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 02 15 e2 c5 6d b5 df fb 48 d2 b0 60 d0 f5 a7 10 96 e0 00 00 00 00 c5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0006 A0 00 A0 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x000a 01
```

`hciconfig` and `hcitool` are part of linux or these are Bluez commands? I used Bluez to create a beacon in a Raspberry Pi and I want to understand what is the exact role of Bluez in all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `hciconfig` and `hcictrl` are BlueZ command line tools.  Systems without BlueZ installed will not have these commands.